# Removing a QWidget from a QTreeWidgetItem without deleting it

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget

I would like to delete an QWidgetItem from QTreeWidget without deleting the corresponding QWidget.

I am using Qt 4.8 and need to create a QTreeWidget, which I update periodically Updating means: deleting all QTreeWidgetItems and creating/inserting new ones.

Because I am not able to create new QWidgets at run-time, I would like to create 100 QWidgets at the beginning, store them in a vector and reuse them for the QTreeWidget. But if I insert a QWidget into the QTreeWidget and remove it (without deleting them) the QWidget gets deleted anyway.

I understand, that this behavior is normally desirable (because of link between ownership and deletion in Qt), but I would like to omit it anyway.

As this question is more about a concept or idea as a solution, I will not append any code, from that I know, that it is wrong...

I would very appreciate any help! Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Try https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html#takeTopLevelItem and if that solves your problem, then you might want to write an answer showing some actual code and how you use that (because half of the point of SO is to generate answers for others too).

Comment: Do you also change the item layout within the tree? If not, you can simply update the data stored in the items: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtreewidgetitem.html#setData

Comment: @hyde: I am tried using only [link](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html#removeItemWidget), only takeTopLevelItem (as you sugested) and both together. But in all cases the removed QWidget is geting deleyed. I gues,  because its parent (= the QTreeItem) is gettinge deleyed. 
As I am strugeling with this problems for some days I certainly will post a solution!

Comment: @Kef: Yes, I have. I have to change the number of TopItems and their children. I could try to pass around the QWidgets between the Items and hide the not-used ones... But this would be a pretty ugly solution...

Comment: Pardon me asking, but why you don't use QAbstractItemModel and QTreeView? widget based views are rather inconvenient for all but the most simple use cases.

Comment: @Kef. Well, I Thought it would be the easiest one...
I need to use different frames for the rows (no frame, dashed lines or solid lines) and use different row heights.
But as I don't see any solution for my problem with QWidgets I will try with QAbstractItemModel!
Thank you for your suggestion!